# tornado handles multiple requests at the same time

Tags: python-3.x, tornado

I want to be able to handle more than two requests at the same time.
I hope the program will start to execute when I visit the `index`, and the `index` can stop when I visit the `stop`.
But the current effect is that the program can process other requests after the `index` is executed.
Can it be implemented under windows?

```py
import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
import time
tag = False

def main():
    for i in range(10):
        global tag
        time.sleep(3)
        print(f"this == {i}")
        print(f"this tag == {tag}")
        if tag == True:
            print("-- stop stop --")
            return "main"
    return "IndexHandler"

class IndexHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        global tag
        tag = False
        print(f"tag == {tag}")
        result = main()
        self.write(result)


class StopHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        global tag
        tag = True
        print(f"tag == {tag}")
        self.write("StopHandler")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/index", IndexHandler),
        (r"/stop", StopHandler),
    ],)
    app.listen(2222)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

Answer (score 0):

`time.sleep` is a blocking function, i.e. it blocks the whole program.

You need to use an asynchronous function to suspend the coroutine, such as `tornado.gen.sleep`.

You'll also need to convert your functions to coroutines (using `aync/await` syntax).

Example:

```
import tornado.gen

async def main():
    for i in range(10):
        # ...
        await tornado.gen.sleep(3)
        # ...


class IndexHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    async def get(self):
        # ...
        result = await main()
```

Comment: My main function will call many other functions, other functions are not asynchronous, do I just need to rewrite main?